# Dirt simple reactjs program - why is the data not displaying?

Tags: html, reactjs

everyone. I've got data in an array and it is getting stored just fine as far as I can tell (it shows up on console when called from the array). But it is not showing up as output. I am totally lost at this point. The code is below and also you can see my work in Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/pen/GqbpQj). If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is the HTML5:

```
<div id="content" >
</div>
```

Here is the reactjs:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({  
    render:function(){
    return(
      <div >
    <h1>Here is the data</h1>
    <AllData />
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var AllData = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
     var theList = [];
      $.getJSON( 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
        function(data) {
         theList = data;
         var steencamp
          for(var i=0; i<10; i++){       
            steencamp = theList[i]
            console.log(steencamp)
            return (
              <div><p>{steencamp}</p></div>
            );
        }
    })
  }            
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not be doing an ajax request in your render function. render should be used to display data only.

```
var AllData = React.createClass({
    dataUrl: 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []}
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        $.getJSON(this.dataUrl, this.handleData)
    },
    handleData: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
    },
    render: function(){
        var elems = [];
        for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
            elems.push(<div><p>{this.state.data[i]}</p></div>);
        }

        return <div>{elems}</div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes more sense. And it should work. But it does not. "Here is the data" is all that shows up on my screen. I've tried return <div>{elems}</div>; and return (<div>{elems}</div>); I've tried making var elems = []; global. I've got the min.js and the react-dom.min.js as well as the jquery preprocessors running in the background. What am I missing?

Comment: @John what is "here is the data"? and have you tried doing a console.log() on the data in your handleData function? i suspect the data coming back is not what you think it is

Comment: Actually, with one small tweak it now does exactly what I was looking for:

Comment: One question more, please --- can you please just shed some light on what that handleData function is doing. Thanks!

Comment: The scope of your question leaves me no idea what you are getting and what you should be returning. The username out of an object is what I'm referring to. The handle data function is what handles the data in the call back from your request. Do you know what state is in a component?

Comment: Yep, console.log() came to the rescue again and I could see what the data was actually doing. I have posted the working code (see below). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({  
    render:function(){
    return(
      <div >
    <h1>Here is the data</h1>
    <AllData />
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var AllData = React.createClass({

    dataUrl: 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {data: []}
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        $.getJSON(this.dataUrl, this.handleData)
    },
    handleData: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
    },
    render: function(){
        var elems = [];
        for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
            elems.push(<div><p>{this.state.data[i].username}</p></div>); 
        }
        return (<div>{elems}</div>);
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
```

);